# bash: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, sed, rhel, gnome, tilix

On a test server I purposefully deleted `?????` in `/` - I was expecting the symlink `/lib64` and the `/media` directory to be deleted. All went well (everything broke), but then I was curious about the output below:

```
[root@testserver /]# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  rh_share3  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
[root@testserver /]# rm -rf ?????
bash: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory
[root@testserver /]# ls
bash: /usr/bin/ls: No such file or directory
bash: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory
```

I see that some packages have `sed` as a dependency, but I'm not understanding why it's calling `sed` for something as simple as pressing `Enter`

```
[root@testserver bin]# rpm -q --whatrequires sed
krb5-libs-1.17-18.el8.x86_64
ca-certificates-2019.2.32-80.0.el8_1.noarch
dracut-049-70.git20200228.el8.x86_64
crypto-policies-20191128-2.git23e1bf1.el8.noarch
policycoreutils-2.9-9.el8.x86_64
authselect-libs-1.1-2.el8.x86_64
cups-filters-1.20.0-19.el8.x86_64
open-vm-tools-11.0.0-4.el8.x86_64
authselect-compat-1.1-2.el8.x86_64
dhcp-client-4.3.6-40.el8.x86_64
nfs-utils-2.3.3-31.el8.x86_64
autofs-5.1.4-40.el8.x86_64
```

Why does the line `bash: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory` show up? Obviously `sed` is considered missing, but why is it being called at all? It is also not mentioned if I just run a `strace -o bash bash`. I know `sed` stands for `stream editor` - is every bash command run through `sed`, or what else could be going on?

The OS is an OOTB RHEL 8.2 (Oopta) with a GUI.

**EDIT**

Below is the output of `set | grep sed`:

```
[user1@testserver ~]$ set | grep sed
    local command=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed 's/^ *[0-9]\+ *//');
                COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( bpftool help 2>&1 |                     command sed                     -e '/OBJECT := /!d'                     -e 's/.*{//'                     -e 's/}.*//'                     -e 's/|//g' )" -- "$cur" ));
    COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W "$( bpftool -jp btf 2>&1 |         command sed -n 's/.*"id": \(.*\),$/\1/p' )" -- "$cur" ))
    COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W "$( bpftool -jp map  2>&1 |         command sed -n 's/.*"id": \(.*\),$/\1/p' )" -- "$cur" ))
    COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W "$( bpftool -jp map  2>&1 |         command grep -C2 "$type" |         command sed -n 's/.*"id": \(.*\),$/\1/p' )" -- "$cur" ))
    COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W "$( bpftool -jp prog 2>&1 |         command sed -n 's/.*"id": \(.*\),$/\1/p' )" -- "$cur" ))
    COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W "$( bpftool -jp prog 2>&1 |         command sed -n 's/.*"tag": "\(.*\)",$/\1/p' )" -- "$cur" ))
    type=$(bpftool -jp map show $keyword $ref |         command sed -n 's/.*"type": "\(.*\)",$/\1/p');
        COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( command sed -ne 's|^iface \([^ ]\{1,\}\).*$|\1|p'            /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.d/* 2>/dev/null )"             -- "$cur" ));
            COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( printf '%s\n'             /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-* |             command sed -ne 's|.*ifcfg-\([^*].*\)$|\1|p' )" -- "$cur" ));
                COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( command ls -B             /etc/sysconfig/interfaces |             command sed -ne 's|.*ifcfg-\([^*].*\)$|\1|p' )" -- "$cur" ));
                COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( printf '%s\n'             /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-* |             command sed -ne 's|.*ifcfg-\([^*].*\)$|\1|p' )" -- "$cur" ));
    local included=$( command sed -ne 's/^[[:blank:]]*[Ii][Nn][Cc][Ll][Uu][Dd][Ee][[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([^#%]*\)\(#.*\)\{0,1\}$/\1/p' "${configfile}" );
    COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W         "$( { LC_ALL=C ifconfig -a || ip addr show; } 2>/dev/null | command sed -ne             's/.*addr:\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/p' -ne             's|.*inet[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]/]*\).*|\1|p' )"         -- "$cur" ))
    [[ $# -ge $OPTIND ]] && echo "error: $FUNCNAME("$@"): unprocessed arguments:" $(while [[ $# -ge $OPTIND ]]; do printf '%s\n' ${!OPTIND}; shift; done);
        local hosts=$( command sed -ne 's/^[[:blank:]]*[Hh][Oo][Ss][Tt][[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([^#*?%]*\)\(#.*\)\{0,1\}$/\1/p' "${config[@]}" );
            local argtype=$( LC_ALL=C $1 --help 2>&1 | command sed -ne                 "s|.*$prev\[\{0,1\}=[<[]\{0,1\}\([-A-Za-z0-9_]\{1,\}\).*|\1|p" );
        COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( LC_ALL=C $1 --help 2>&1 |             command sed -ne 's/.*\(--[-A-Za-z0-9]\{1,\}=\{0,1\}\).*/\1/p' | sort -u )"             -- "$cur" ));
    COMPREPLY+=($(         { LC_ALL=C ifconfig -a || ip link show; } 2>/dev/null | command sed -ne         "s/.*[[:space:]]HWaddr[[:space:]]\{1,\}\($re\)[[:space:]].*/\1/p" -ne         "s/.*[[:space:]]HWaddr[[:space:]]\{1,\}\($re\)[[:space:]]*$/\1/p" -ne         "s|.*[[:space:]]\(link/\)\{0,1\}ether[[:space:]]\{1,\}\($re\)[[:space:]].*|\2|p" -ne         "s|.*[[:space:]]\(link/\)\{0,1\}ether[[:space:]]\{1,\}\($re\)[[:space:]]*$|\2|p"
    COMPREPLY+=($( { arp -an || ip neigh show; } 2>/dev/null | command sed -ne         "s/.*[[:space:]]\($re\)[[:space:]].*/\1/p" -ne         "s/.*[[:space:]]\($re\)[[:space:]]*$/\1/p" ));
    COMPREPLY+=($( command sed -ne         "s/^[[:space:]]*\($re\)[[:space:]].*/\1/p" /etc/ethers 2>/dev/null ));
    COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "$( command ls -RL $modpath 2>/dev/null |         command sed -ne 's/^\(.*\)\.k\{0,1\}o\(\.[gx]z\)\{0,1\}$/\1/p' )" -- "$cur" ))
        COMPREPLY=($( compgen -X '<defunct>'             -W '$( command ps axo comm | command sed -e 1d )' -- "$cur" ));
        COMPREPLY=($( compgen -X '<defunct>' -W '$( command ps axo command= | command sed -e \
        COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W '`command sed -e "y/|/ /" \
    COMPREPLY+=($( compgen -W         "$( command sed -ne 's/^\([^[:space:]#|]\{2,\}\)|.*/\1/p' /etc/termcap             2>/dev/null )" -- "$cur" ));
```

Comment: `set|grep sed` should show you where set is used in shell option suggestions/filename completions etc.

Comment: And that's it. Filename completion. simple as that. `bash` tries to look up comletions with `sed` and this triggers the error.

Comment: @stoney, how does filename completion come into it if you just typed `ls` and hit enter, without tabbing?

Comment: I would rather say that editing history file need a bit of `sed`

Comment: Can you also post output of `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` and `echo $PS1`?

Comment: You may have `PROMPT_COMMAND` set to something that calls `sed`. Or calls some non-existing command, which in turn triggers the `command_not_found_handle()` function which in turn may be calling `sed`. Or something completely different. If you have fun trashing your system by removing essential files and directories, keep the fun on until you get to the bottom of it, rather than trying to collect wildly innacurate guesses about what that could mean.

Comment: I wonder if it is PackageKit-command-not-found that is calling sed?

Answer (score 2):

The file that is causing this behavior is `vte.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/`:

> One aspect of VTE configuration is the use of `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh`.
> The VTE uses this script to override the `PROMPT_COMMAND` in order to
> feed itself additional information via terminal control codes. In
> particular, this script is used to tell the VTE the current directory
> of the shell. Previously the VTE component used to read this from
> `/proc/<pid>/cwd` however according to VTE upstream there were a number
> of issues with this approach and hence the change to
> `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh`.

[Source](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/manual/vteconfig/)

This behavior does not occur over SSH, only when using the GNOME Terminal. If anyone with a better understanding of window systems would like to write a more detailed answer, I would be glad to accept as my understanding of GNOME is limited at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the problem is that you've overridden `command`, a builtin:

```
$ help command | head --lines=2
command: command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
    Execute a simple command or display information about commands.
```

`command` is commonly used to ignore aliases and functions to explicitly run the builtin or executable directly. This is useful to avoid infinite loops. For example:

```
ls() {
    command ls --color=auto
}
```

This calls the `ls` executable instead of calling itself recursively forever.

`unset command` and look for any uses of `command` in your Bash profile.

Answer (score 0):

This is just speculation, but `sed` is probably a dynamically-linked 64-bit binary. By deleting `lib64`, the kernel can no longer locate the dynamic linker needed to execute `sed` (and probably just about everything else). The `no such file or directory` isn't for `sed`, it's for the linker.

Answer (score 0):

it's due to /etc/profile.d/vte.sh

```
case "$TERM" in
  xterm*|vte*)
    [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && PROMPT_COMMAND="__vte_prompt_command"
    [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION"  ] && precmd_functions+=(__vte_osc7)
    ;;
esac
vte_prompt_command() {
  ######### HERE : bash tries to look up comletions with sed ###
  local command=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed 's/^ *[0-9]\+ *//')
  ############################################################
  command="${command//;/ }"
  local pwd='~'
  [ "$PWD" != "$HOME" ] && pwd=${PWD/#$HOME\//\~\/}
  printf "\033]777;notify;Command completed;%s\007\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007%s" "${command}" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${pwd}" "$(__vte_osc7)"
}
```

just delete this(then you must use correct filename)

```
sed 's/^ *[0-9]\+ *//'
```

fixed!